# How to change the link in jdownloads in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, hyperlink

I am new to Joomla. Whenever I click the link on some download link the page is redirected to `/component/jdownloads/viewdownload/`. How can I change the link as `/download/viewdownload/categoryexample/downloadname`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URLs are created by the jDownloads router, you will have to hack that if you want to change how it determines a URL. You will also have to be careful with updates since that is a file likely to be replaced when you update the component. Be sure to document the changes and keep a copy in case you need to make the edits again after an update.

If jDownloads does not have a router, then you will have to right one. Here's a good start in understanding how the router works - http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component